# How to add 'Company Name' in customer register and billing info

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I've been trying to add 'company name' on customer register and onepage checkout but unsuccessfully so far. I tried https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/add-company-name-to-billing-shipping-dropdown-in-magento  but it didn't help at all.

I can't believe there isn't a simple way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The company field is already part of the address entity in Magento, if it isn't showing on register and checkout forms you'll need to update the templates to include it.

I recommend that you look in either the base/default or rwd/default theme and look at:

- checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
- persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
- persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

You should see company in there and can copy that into your active theme.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Adding a new field to Magento new customer registration can be done in 4 simple steps. Follow the steps given below to get done with it.

**Step 1:** We have to add php and .html form elements that are necessary to create new input boxes for each additional field in register.phtml.

```
<div class="input-box">
<label for=”company_name”><?php echo $this->__('Company Name') ?></label><br/>
<input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company Name') ?>" class="input-text" />
</div>
```

**Step 2:** We need to add elements under “getDefaultEntities()” in Setup.php (path: /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/), one for each additional field created above:

```
company_name' => array(
'label' => 'Company Name',
'required' => false,
'sort_order' => 64,
),
```

**Step 3:** Add to the content of $customer in AccountController.php (path: /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/) by grabbing the new fields from posted info, in the createPostAction() function:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->
setCompany($this->getRequest()->getPost('company_name'));
```

**Step 4:** Finally, we will need to add database records to table eav_attribute, corresponding to the newly created fields. The idea is to add to the associated data model, where newly defined model data is entered as the “attribute_code”, with the corresponding entity_type_id (which for this data happens to be ‘1’).

Using your favourite SQL editor (i.e. phpMySQL or sqlYog — highly recommended), execute the following SQL statement for each field created above (replacing ‘company’ and ‘Company Name’ with the respective field name information as required):

INSERT INTO eav_attribute (entity_type_id, attribute_code, backend_type, frontend_input, frontend_label, is_global,is_visible, is_required, is_configurable, is_filterable_in_search) VALUES(’1′, ‘company’, ‘varchar’,  ‘text’, ‘Company Name’, ’1′, ’1′, ’0′,  ’1′,  ’1′);